# Sloved - How to send Textbox value from WinForm to MS Access Form designed with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a projet in Visual studio winform with c#, and I have a form design in Microsoft Access, and I'm tryin to open the MS Access Form, from Visual studio Form, I find how to do it with this code :

```cs
Access.Application oAccess = null;
// Start a new instance of Access for Automation:
oAccess = new Access.Application();
// Open a database in exclusive mode:   


oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(Application.StartupPath + @"\\MyDB_Name.mdb", //filepath
    true //Exclusive
);

// Show a form named Employees:
oAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm(
    "MyForm_Name", //FormName
    Access.AcFormView.acNormal, //View
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, //FilterName
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, //WhereCondition
    Access.AcFormOpenDataMode.acFormEdit, //DataMode
    Access.AcWindowMode.acDialog,//WindowMode
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value //OpenArgs
);
```

Rigth now it works to open the MS Access form but i need to show it inside a form in my projet like when you display pdf in form !

and the important question is how i can to send value from textbox in visual studio to MS Access textbox !

I found this code but it's for MS Word Model :

```cs
string MyMessage = Application.StartupPath + @"\\MyDataBase_Name.dotx";
Word.Application myApp1 = new Word.Application();
Word.Document myDoc1 = new Word.Document();
myDoc1 = myApp1.Documents.Open(MyMessage);
myDoc1.Activate();
Word.Bookmarks bokmk = myDoc1.Bookmarks;
bokmk["WRD_txt1"].Range.Text = TextBox1.Text;
bokmk["WRD_txt2"].Range.Text = TextBox2.Text;
bokmk["WRD_txt3"].Range.Text = TextBox3.Text;
```

Comment: this sounds like a recipe for a big mess. Why do you want to do this? Wouldn't it be better just to re-implement the Access GUI entirely in WinForms? And then maybe replace Access with something better, as well...

Comment: I did not have a choice, I wanted to print a letter, for example, in the Word file, but the professor as told me to use  the Access form so that we do not have to open Word and Excel in the same time because my data base hosted in MS Access.
I think your idea is excellent! Instead of opening the MS Access form, I think I should draw it in the Visual Studio and print it.
if you have any example i will be thanksfull

Comment: I don't have a specific example but I'm sure you can find information online about how to connect your application to use Access as a database, and run queries against it to get data.

Comment: thank you but i change my idea , i think the best solution is to desing in winform a model like access form model and print it ? you think it will work great ?

Comment: yes that's a good idea. But presumably you still need the data from the Access database, even if you don't need the user interface any more?

Comment: the data i have it in a grid and when i click in row of grid ,the row fill some textbox so when i click print the textbox value fill the textbox field in new form who have the model like MS Access , this is it , thank you for your idea

Comment: @ADyson Thank you you save my day